# Using Scheme to find the least element in a list

Tags: scheme, tail-recursion

```
(define min
  (lambda (l m c)
    (cond ((null? l) (print m))
          (else ((c (car l))
                 if((< c m) (m c))
                 min((cdr l) m c))))))
```

I want to use the tail-recursive method to do it,but it doesn't work. I'm very very new in Scheme, hope you can help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like homework, I'll give you some pointers so you can solve it by yourself. Fill-in the blanks:

```
(define (mymin lst minval)
  (cond ((null? lst)        ; If the list is empty
         ???)               ; return the minimum value.
        ((< ??? minval)     ; If current element < minimum value
         (mymin ??? ???))   ; advance recursion, current element is new minimum.
        (else               ; If current element >= minimum value
         (mymin ??? ???)))) ; advance recursion, keep the same minimum.
```

In the above code, we're implementing a two-parameter tail-recursive procedure called `mymin` (don't use the name `min`, that's a built-in procedure.) The first parameter is the list to traverse; the second parameter stores the minimum value found so far, and when the recursion ends, it will hold the answer.

Call it like this, noticing that for the first call we need to pass in the second argument a number so big that all the other numbers are smaller:

```
(mymin '(1 2 3 4 0 5) +inf.0)
> 0
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to initialize the minval as the first element of lst, what can I do? I mean I don't need to put into the value of minval by myself, and there will only be one argument in the function mymin.

Comment: Well, you could pass the first element of the list as the initial value of minval, just be careful - if the list is empty it will not have a first value. Write a helper function that receives a single list as a parameter (it's easy, I'm not going to do that for you!) and from it, call the above procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Oscar's version will work but I have some stylistic quibbles (this is not a dig at Oscar, who is keeping it simple to make the solution plainer).  If you get it working along those lines, see if you can make a couple of changes.

**No spurious parameters**

You have 3 parameters and Oscar has two but this is a list that takes one input - a list.  Give the wrong extra seed parameters and you'll fail.  One way to fix this is to recur *inside* the main function.  It could look something like this

```
(define (mymin lst)
  (let ((minval ???))
    (define (findmin lst testval)
      (cond
        (????)
        (????)
        (????))
    (findmin lst minval)))
```

Do you see how that works?  You could initialise minval to inf.0, as Oscar did, or to a special non-numerical value (there are a couple of good choices, one better than the other).

If you're really smart, though, you'll see that there's no need to pass two values each time.  You can pass one simple object to each recursion, with no need for an inner function or any initialisation - why initialise anything with infinite values when you have all the data you need at the start?

Here's a clue to how it would look (it starts much like Oscar's version):

```
(define (mymin lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst) ???)
    ((?????) (car lst))
    (else (mymin (??????????????????????? lst)))))
```

There are a few things going on in that last line of ???s ;)

But only try for these improvements once you have a working version, unless you can't get it working any other way.  Get it working, then improve - you learn twice ;)

Some things to think about, along the way...

- What do you return if there's only one element in the list?
- What's the simplest way to test if there's only one element in the list?
- What's the most logical thing to return if the list is empty?

Comment: Ah, I see from the comments that you know you'd like to do something like my second solution but aren't sure how - you have good instincts.  Between Oscar's hints in the comments and my sketch above, you can do it.